# Firebase Push notification is not Received when i kill the app?

Tags: php, android, ios

1. FCM Notification is working fine when the app is foreground & background
2. Notification is not working when we kill the app?

My payload:

```
notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      }
"data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
   }
```

Comment: if you are killing app service manually than dear their is now way you will get notification android does not work that way

Answer (score 0):

You always receive PUSH Notifications through FCM. But how notifications are received is different in both cases i.e. when app is in background and foreground. You have to check for it. Killing App will not effect it unless you stop service. If service is stopped, you won't receive notifications.

Second, if you are overriding `onDataChange()` and want to show notification whenever data changes then know that this function only executes when app is in foreground or not killed.